# mongodb: upserting: only set value if document is being inserted

Tags: mongodb

Considering a simple mongo document structure:

{ _id, firstTime, lastTime }

The client needs to insert a document with a known ID, or update an existing document. The 'lastTime' should always be set to some latest time. For the 'firstTime', if a document is being inserted, then the 'firstTime' should be set to current time. However, if the document is already created, then 'firstTime' remain unchanged. I would like to do it purely with upserts (to avoid look ups).

I've crawled the http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating, but I just don't see how that particular operation can be done.

I don't believe this is something unreasonable, there are $push and $addToSet operations that effectively do that on array fields, just nothing that would do the same on simple fields. It's like there should be something like $setIf operation.

Comment: *if the document is already created, the field should remain unchanged*  it doesn't called upsert (as in your title)

Comment: @om-nom-nom I've outline the most simplest case, I've updated the description, so there is a field that is always being updated.

Comment: Looks like this feature is targeted for 2.4:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-340

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem and there was no simple solution for <2.4 however since 2.4 the **$setOnInsert** operator let's you do exactly that.

```
db.collection.update( <query>,
                      { $setOnInsert: { "firstTime": <TIMESTAMP> } },
                      { upsert: true }
                    )
```

See the [2.4 release notes of setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a very similar problem when attempting to upsert documents based on existing content--maybe this solution will work for you also:

Try removing the _id attribute from your record and only use it in the query portion of your update (you'll have to translate from pymongo speak...)

```
myid = doc.get('_id')
del doc['_id']
mycollection.update({'_id':myid}, {'$set':doc}, upsert=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will trigger the following code 2 subsequent times, it will first set both `firstVisit` and `lastVisit` on document insert (and will return `upsertedId` in the response) and on the second it will only update `lastVisit` (and will return `modifiedCount: 1`).

Tested with Mongo 4.0.5 though I believe should be working with older versions.

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  {_id: 1}, 
  { 
    $set: { 
      lastVisit: Date.now() 
    }, 
    $setOnInsert: {
      firstVisit: Date.now()
    }
  }, 
  { upsert: true }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

There's no way to do this with just one upsert.  You'd have to do it as 2 operations - first try to insert the document, if it already exists the insert will fail due to duplicate key violation on the _id index.  Then you do an update operation to set the lastTime to now.

Comment: IMHO, this will defeat the purpose, doing, and waiting for, the first operation amounts to synchronous look up. I don't see a difference in "attempt to fail" and find and update...

Comment: There is a race condition with the find and update and update approach with multiple concurrent writers.  If another writer comes in and creates/changes the document between when the first thread did the read and when it does the write, you can wind up overriding the write that the other thread did.

Comment: That's why I want it in a single write() operation, so to ask Mongo to execute it atomically.